# How to send web request in queue in C# windows application

Tags: c#

I made an application to trigger web request from window application and forget,means without waiting response.

```
            string url1 = APIUrl + "/SendNotification";
            string url2 = Url + "/SendSOA";

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url1);
            request.Method = "Post";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.GetResponseAsync(); //Mohan: Method will not wait for response just trigger and forget

            ASCIIEncoding encoding1 = new ASCIIEncoding();
            HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url2);
            request1.Method = "Post";
            request1.ContentLength = 0;
            request1.ContentType = "application/json";
            request1.GetResponseAsync(); //Mohan: Method will not wait for response just trigger and forget
```

but when I am trying it by local host URL that time I see that these two methods are running means second request is not waiting for to complete first request so I want to send request in Queue then it will complete first Request and then will complete second request.

means till one request is not completed second request should be in queue.
once First request is completed then second request start in my web

I tried it

```
            string APIUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIUrl"].ToString();
            string Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"].ToString();

            Queue httprequest = new Queue();
            string url1 = APIUrl + "/SendNotification";
            string url2 = Url + "/SendSOA";

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url1);
            request.Method = "Post";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            httprequest.Enqueue(request);
            request.GetResponseAsync(); //Mohan: Method will not wait for response just trigger and forget

            ASCIIEncoding encoding1 = new ASCIIEncoding();
            HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url2);
            request1.Method = "Post";
            request1.ContentLength = 0;
            request1.ContentType = "application/json";
            httprequest.Enqueue(request1);
            request1.GetResponseAsync(); //Mohan: Method will not wait for response just trigger and forget
```

but still its not waiting to complete first request.

my web methods are

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
    public async Task SendNotification()
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
    public async Task SendSOA()
    {

    }
```

please help me to do it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It depends on how you want the two requests to execute. You could use the await pattern or the Task continue with method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [task continuations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks) for this purpose. Something like this:

```
        string url1 = APIUrl + "/SendNotification";
        string url2 = Url + "/SendSOA";

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url1);
        request.Method = "Post";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        var firstTask = request.GetResponseAsync();

        firstTask.ContinueWith(_ => {
            ASCIIEncoding encoding1 = new ASCIIEncoding();
            HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url2);
            request1.Method = "Post";
            request1.ContentLength = 0;
            request1.ContentType = "application/json";
            request1.GetResponseAsync(); //Mohan: Method will not wait for response just trigger and forget
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure that your first request is OK?

Comment: Sorry it works fine for me. I forgot to change URL.Thanks v.karbovnichy

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync(v=vs.110).aspx),

> This operation will not block. The returned Task object will complete after a response to an Internet request is available.

Use [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) to wait for the result of your request:

```
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

Comment: I don't want response because i was getting error timeout

Answer (score 0):

You could change the code to be something like this:

```
        ASCIIEncoding encoding1 = new ASCIIEncoding();
        HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url2);
        request1.Method = "Post";
        request1.ContentLength = 0;
        request1.ContentType = "application/json";**strong text**
        var responseTask = request.GetResponseAsync(); //Mohan: Method will not wait for response just trigger and forget
        responseTask.ContinueWith(t=>
        {
          request1.GetResponseAsync();
        });
```

Alternatively you can implement the async/await pattern depending on how you are calling this code.